# im trying to print the csv data in vertical with headers but instead it always prints in a horizontal line. can someone look my code plss

Tags: python, csv, line-breaks

```
def players_stats():
    with open("playerstststsst.csv") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',newline:'\n')
        player = (input("Enter the subject to use as filter:").lower().title())
        for row in csvreader:
            if player in str(row[0]):
                print(row)
```

I have provided the image of the CSV file and
I have tried using line break to put the name, number, position, and date in vertical with a header but it's not working for some reason. I tried everything but it's not working someone please help.

this is the image of the CSV file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyH1M.png)

This is what the results should look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqEVM.png)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You are printing a single line; it's not clear what your expected output should look like. Are you looking for `for field in row: print(field)`?

Comment: is the image you posted the output or is it a spreadsheet? can you post the result of your code?

Comment: Indeed, please [edit] to replace the image with a *small* sample as actual text we can copy and paste, and provide a clarification as to what exactly your expected output should look like.

Comment: Done i have made the edits

Comment: No, you have provided images of text, again. Please review the link above, which contains a substantial list of reasons you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print each field from the row on a separate line, just loop over them.

As an aside, probably refactor your function so it doesn't require interactive input.

```py
def players_stats(player):
    player = player.lower().title()
    with open("playerstststsst.csv") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',newline:'\n')
        for idx, row in enumerate(csvreader):
            if idx == 0:
                titles = row
            # row[0] is already a str, no need to convert
            elif player in row[0]:
                for key, value in zip(titles, row):
                    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

# Let the caller ask the user for input if necessary
pläyers_stats(input("Enter the subject to use as filter:"))
```

Probably a better design for most situations is to read the CSV file into memory at the beginning of your script, and then simply search through the corresponding data structure without needing to touch the disk again.